# How to stop the UITextField from responding to the shake gesture?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, shake

By default, if you shake the iPhone while entering text in a `UITextField`, a little box will appear asking if you want to undo typing. How can I prevent this from happening? I looked through the [`UITextField`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html), [`UITextFieldDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate), and [`UITextInputTraits`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits) docs and found nothing relating to shaking.

Presumably I could subclass `UITextField` to ignore the shake event, but I'm not exactly confident in my ability to not screw other things up. I'd love something like

```
textField.respondsToShake = FALSE;
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = NO;
```

Comment: This should be set in webViewDidFinishLoad method.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to subclass `UITextField` and override `canPerformAction:withSender:` in such a way that it will disallow the `undo:` action. But then you lose undo both by shaking and through the context menu.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mention that I wasn't worried about removing undo entirely in application, and it looks like there's an easier way, but this is a nice answer that I'll probably use in the future.